# General formula for roots for cubic equation

Tags: calculus, math-software

I have the following cubic equation with  $ \beta \in [0,1]$ and  $ \delta\in [0,1]$ are 2 parameters. Is it possible to use software to get the explicit expression of the solution.

\begin{equation*}
U^{3}\left( -\left( \frac{\delta^{2}}{2} + \beta\right)+\delta-\frac{1}{2} \right)+U^{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}-\delta-\left( \frac{\delta^{2}}{2} + \beta\right)\right)+U\left(\left( \frac{\delta^{2}}{2}+\beta -2 \delta\right)\right)+\left( \frac{\delta^{2}}{2} + \beta\right)=0
\end{equation*}

I want to solve this equation usin Maple or Mathematica, but I was not able to do it.

Comment: Is $U$ the variable name?

Comment: @lea: Forgive my not using symbols, but http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28-%28a%5E2%2F2%29%2Ba-1%2F2%29u%5E3+%2B+%283%2F2-a-%28a%5E2%2F2%2Bb%29%29u%5E2%2B%28a%5E2%2F2%2Bb-2+c%29u+%2B+%28a%5E2%2F2%2Bb%29+%3D+0+for+u

Comment: BISHD , yes U is the variable

Comment: Amzoti, thank's a lot for the answer

Comment: @lea: My apologies, I had messed up one of the variable names, but here is the corrected one: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28-%28a%5E2%2F2%29%2Ba-1%2F2%29u%5E3+%2B+%283%2F2-a-%28a%5E2%2F2%2Bb%29%29u%5E2%2B%28a%5E2%2F2%2Bb-2+a%29u+%2B+%28a%5E2%2F2%2Bb%29+%3D+0+for+u

Comment: Amzoti < is it possible to use other function in this link wolframalpha, I want to solve the following equation 
$\left[ \Phi\left( \dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\delta\right] \phi\left( \dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)+\left[ \dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right] f\left( \Phi\left( \dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right) =0$

with $f(p)=\dfrac{p^{2}}{2}- \delta p+\left( \dfrac{\delta^{2}}{2} + \beta\right)$

Where $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are the cumulative distribution and  the density function of Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find formula for cubic equation in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation

I will shortly describe the process how to solve such equation. This can be done in steps to minimize the use of long complicated expressions.

**Step 1:** write $aU^3 + bU^2 + cU + d = 0$.

**Step 2:** reduce to the case $T^3 + pT + q = 0$ (as explained in Wikipedia, divide the equation by $a \ne 0$ and then subsitute $U = T - \frac{b}{3a}$).

**Step 3:** use Cardano's formula. Taking the real cubic roots you get
$$ T_{\mathbb{R}}=u+v=\sqrt[3]{-{q\over 2}+ \sqrt{{q^{2}\over 4}+{p^{3}\over 27}}} +\sqrt[3]{-{q\over 2}- \sqrt{{q^{2}\over 4}+{p^{3}\over 27}}} $$

**Step 4:** to find the rest of the roots divide $T^3 + pT + q$ by $T-T_{mathbb{R}}$ and then solve the quadratic that you get.

In all the steps you intermediate parameters-variables, e.g. 
$$ A = -\left( \frac{\delta^2}{2} + \beta \right) + \delta - \frac{1}{2} $$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots) for a general formula for cubic roots.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.